# Подсчёт ЧАСТИЧНО совпадающих элементов в списке

Tags: python

**Дано**: список "карт на руках" (моделируем игру). Элементы списка представлены в виде строк типа: '6♡' или '10♣'.

**ВОПРОС**: Как грамотно выявить карты с повторяющимся номиналом, то есть рассматривая только строки с отброшенным последним символом, обозначающим масть? Чтобы результат выводился в виде объекта, где элементы расположены в порядке убывания повторений. Уже имеется функция getnominal(card), которая выводит числовое значение номинала. На ум приходит только составление отдельного списка, где будут только номиналы, но кажется, это слишком неграмотный подход.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть список:

```
items = ['4♣', '4♡', '6♡', '10♣', '9♣']
```

#### Подсчет по масти и по номиналу:

```
number = sum(1 for x in items if '♣' in x)
print(number)
# 3

number = sum(1 for x in items if '4' in x[:-1])
print(number)
# 2
```

#### Сортировка по масти и с номиналом по убыванию:

```
new_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: (x[-1], int(x[:-1])), reverse=True)
print(new_items)
# ['10♣', '9♣', '4♣', '6♡', '4♡']
```

#### Группирование по масти, где масть будет ключом, а значением список карт с этой мастью:

```
from collections import defaultdict

suit_by_card = defaultdict(list)
for x in items:
    suit = x[-1]
    suit_by_card[suit].append(x)
print(suit_by_card)
# {'♣': ['4♣', '10♣', '9♣'], '♡': ['4♡', '6♡']}
```

#### Аналогично выше, только ключом будет номинал:

```
value_by_card = defaultdict(list)
for x in items:
    value = int(x[:-1])
    value_by_card[value].append(x)
print(value_by_card)
# {'4': ['4♣', '4♡'], '6': ['6♡'], '10': ['10♣'], '9': ['9♣']}
```

#### Пример использования [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) для составления списка дубликатов:

```
from collections import Counter

items = ['4♣', '4♡', '9♣', '4♡', '6♡', '4♡', '10♣', '9♣']

card_by_number = Counter(items)
print(card_by_number)
# {'4♡': 3, '9♣': 2, '4♣': 1, '6♡': 1, '10♣': 1}

duplicates = [k for k, v in card_by_number.items() if v > 1]
print(duplicates)
# ['4♡', '9♣']
```

**UPD.**

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = ['6♠', '9♠', '9♡', '10♢', '13♠', '13♡', '13♢', '14♣']

value_by_card = defaultdict(list)
for x in items:
    value = int(x[:-1])
    value_by_card[value].append(x)
print(value_by_card)
# {6: ['6♠'], 9: ['9♠', '9♡'], 10: ['10♢'], 13: ['13♠', '13♡', '13♢'], 14: ['14♣']}

order_nums = []
nums = sorted(value_by_card.keys(), reverse=True)
for num in nums:
    cards = value_by_card[num]
    print(cards)
    order_nums.append(cards)
# ['14♣']
# ['13♠', '13♡', '13♢']
# ['10♢']
# ['9♠', '9♡']
# ['6♠']

print(order_nums)
# [['14♣'], ['13♠', '13♡', '13♢'], ['10♢'], ['9♠', '9♡'], ['6♠']]
```

---

**PS.**

- `x[-1]` -- это возвращает последний символ `10♣` -> `♣`
- `x[:-1]` -- это возвращает всё, кроме последнего символа `10♣` -> `10`

Comment: Так это же получается подсчёт по масти, а не по номиналу, если я правильно понял... А надо, чтобы подсчитывалось количество "пятёрок", "десяток" и т. д. Похожий функционал есть вроде бы в collections.Counter(), но там я не вижу, как посчитать по ЧАСТИ элемента...

Comment: @Leo, ага, ошибся :) обновил ответ

Comment: Вот этот вариант частично решил задачу: "Аналогично выше, только ключом будет номинал:", но парные карты он вывел в начало списка, так как они там изначально и стояли. Не подскажете, как всё же отсортировать произвольный словарь, чтобы вначале шли элементы с максимальной длиной value, и по убыванию. То есть, если на руках три туза, две дамы и дальше по одной, то он их в таком порядке и расставит, исходя из количества одинаковых номиналов, как бы мы ни мешали карты в исходом списке. Опыта работы со словарями нет, а гугл плохо помогает. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @Leo, а зачем словарь сортировать? Словарь как правило нужен для получения значения по ключу, а ключи это не индексы массива, не всегда есть гарантия их порядка. Поэтому лучше у словаря возьмите ключи, отсортируйте их и обращайтесь к словарю с новым порядком ключей. Обновил пример с `value_by_card`, теперь можно сделать так: `nums = sorted(value_by_card.keys(), reverse=True)` получите номиналы от самого большого к маленькому. Соответственно, вывести карты от большего к меньшему: `for num in nums: print(value_by_card[num])` или просто карты наибольшего номинала: `print(value_by_card[nums[0]])`

Comment: Да, но меня не интересует номинал. Мне надо оценить возможность зайти сразу с двух или трёх карт одинакового номинала, поэтому меня интересует параметр len(value), чтобы понять, где есть наибольшее количество карт одинакового номинала. Есть возможность sort dict by len(value) descending?

Comment: @Leo, у вас в вопросе `Как грамотно выявить карты с повторяющимся номиналом, то есть рассматривая только строки с отброшенным последним символом, обозначающим масть?` у меня в ответе есть пример с таким результатом: `value_by_card`. Предоставьте в вопросе исходный список карт и какой должен быть результат

Comment: Не уверен, что точно объясняю, но я попробую. Дано: ['6♠', '9♠', '9♡', '10♢', '13♠', '13♡', '13♢', '14♣']
На выходе "пачками" должны идти карты с одинаковыми номиналами в порядке убывания длины "пачки" (в виде чего угодно, например, словаря):
['13♠', '13♡', '13♢'], ['9♠', '9♡'], ['6♠'], ['10♢'], ['14♣']

Comment: То есть ваш ответ годится, но элементы словаря надо отсортировать по убыванию длины value.

Comment: @Leo, так понятнее :) Но я об этом вам и писал выше: `nums = sorted(value_by_card.keys()` + `for num in nums: print(value_by_card[num])`. Добавил в ответ как UPD.

Comment: Спасибо. Я немного допилил решение, добавив в конце:
def getlen(card):  # Создаём ключ для сортировки
    return len(card)
order_nums.sort(key = getlen, reverse=True)
Теперь стало, как надо!

Comment: @Leo, хорошо :)